# Как наложить стиль (shadow) на текст кнопки?

Tags: css3

Можно ли на вот эту кнопку привинтить text-shadow?

```
<input type='submit' name='button_2' value='название кнопки' id='button2' style='color:#ffffff; width:230px;'>
```

Вставка в style text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000 ни к чему не приводит, так как это стили батона. Но цвет же я меняю текста, значит CSS на неё работает. А почему не полностью?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Можно](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8T8L/4/). Но, так как CSS3 еще не стандарт, возможно, придется использовать вендорные префиксы (`-moz-`, `-webkit-`, `-o-`, `-ms-` или еще какие).

Возможно, вы перепутали с `box-shadow`?

---

```
<input type='submit' name='button_2' value='название кнопки' id='button2' style='text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px red;'>
```

Comment: Нет. box-Shadow, это box-shadow, а текст, это текст

Comment: Где там Ваша красная тень? Так и не увидел.

Comment: ![Вот же](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/jf59YFcPf4tu9UqlcYhTifaMNRhseIIoZjusV8LrUkE?feat=directlink)

Comment: Это зависит от браузера я протестировал в FireFox 11+ Safari 5.1.5 и Chromium (Интернет) 17.053 работает а в IE<=9 и Opera<=10.5

Comment: @Rules, да вы шо, какая неожиданность! CSS3 еще не стандарт, чтобы работать повсеместно (да и будь стандартом, не факт что...)

Я вот юзаю [`compass`](http://compass-style.org) и не парюсь - вендорные префиксы за меня ставит

Comment: Это для справки @I_CaR :)

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: А! Да вспомнил про этот хак! Спасибо что обновили память.. ато CSS я уже полгода как не вспоминал :)

Comment: @Rules, вы ошибаетесь, это не хак. Хак - это когда `* html div {}` или что-то в этом духе - для IE

Comment: Ну короче спасибо что напомнили про префиксы :)

Comment: Точно! Я то в Опере смотрел!
Safari - ДА
Chrome - Да
FireFoxe - Да
Opera 11.64 - НЕТ!
IExplorer 9 - НЕТ